# Is there a way to get entity id-field's name by reflection or whatever?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, propertyinfo

I am trying to get the ID field name (property name) of an entity, is it possible?

User user= new User(); //User is an Entity

string idField = ??????? //user.UserId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get the EntitySet, or the EntityType, for the entity, then you can use the KeyMembers property:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetIdProperties(EntitySetBase entitySet)
{
  return GetIdProperties(entitySet.ElementType);
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetIdProperties(EntityTypeBase entityType)
{
  return from keyMember in entityType.KeyMembers
         select keyMember.Name
}
```

You can obtain a generic object set from the context:

```
public ObjectSet<TEntity> GetEntitySet<TEntity>(ObjectContext context)
{
    return context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetIdFields<TEntity>() where TEntity
  : EntityObject
{
    var ids = from p in typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()
              where (from a in p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                     where a is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute &&
                       ((EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)a).EntityKeyProperty
                     select true).FirstOrDefault()
              select p.Name;
    return ids;
}

public static string GetIdField<TEntity>() where TEntity : EntityObject
{
    IEnumerable<string> ids = GetIdFields<TEntity>();
    string id = ids.Where(s => s.Trim().StartsWith(typeof(TEntity).Name.
                  Trim())).FirstOrDefault();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) id = ids.First();
    return id;
}
```

You could merge both funcs into one or set your search conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4cfbfa0b-6c07-4c2e-b5f2-19fcc381a4f5/) in the Entity Framework support forums shows how to use reflection to find ID fields and their details.

Answer (score 0):

Entity class is still a class which inherits from System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject, so, i think reflection will still work on it.

Have you tried it? Do you get any error?