# EntityFramework 6 How to get identity-field with reflection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-6

I have a generic method with type parameter T, where T is the type of entity in EF model.
I need to get the name of identifying field in this type.
I saw this article: [Is there a way to get entity id-field's name by reflection or whatever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077497/is-there-a-way-to-get-entity-id-fields-name-by-reflection-or-whatever)
But I can't understand, what Tevin talking about when he talks about **EntitySetBase** and **EntityTypeBase** types.
If **EntityTypeBase** is type of one of the entities in model, so then EF6 have no property **KeyMembers**.

Comment: take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253943/entity-framework-code-first-find-primary-key)

Comment: @YuliamChandra thanks for reply. So, **KeyMembers** getting from context and as I understand code creates entity set which use some system resources. Is there other way to get key-field name with reflection?

Comment: it's not a pure reflection, it needs to get the key name first using edm that is explained in the post, because the key property can be configured as key field by using [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) and [Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.1), which we can't get by reflection only

Comment: Anyway, all the data are in DbContext. Is there no other way to get key Name but create ObjectSet<T> with CreateObjectSet<T>() method???

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get the primary keys only by reflection.

First, let's find out how EF determine which property(ies) that will be primary key(s) regardless of the order / priority

- **By [Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.1)**

> The Entity Framework convention for primary keys is:
>
> 1. Your class defines a property whose name is “ID” or “Id”
> 2. or a class name followed by “ID” or “Id”

We can use `GetProperties` and compare the property name.

```
var key = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => 
    p.Name.Equals("ID", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    || p.Name.Equals(type.Name + "ID", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

- **By [`[KeyAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Key)**

We can use `CustomAttributes` and compare the attribute type.

```
var key = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => 
    p.CustomAttributes.Any(attr => attr.AttributeType == typeof(KeyAttribute)));
```

- **By [Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.1)**

This is the one that's difficult to do, `modelBuilder` is encapsulated in the `OnModelCreating` and even if we save the `modelBuilder` somewhere as field/property, it's still difficult to extract the key from `HasKey` function, everything is encapsulated. You can check the [source code](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). And everything in EF depends on [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and once the `ObjectContext` is called, for example this line of code,

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext
```

then a connection to the database will be made, you can check using profiler. And here is the code excerpt of the source code.

```
public override ObjectContext ObjectContext
{
    get
    {
        Initialize();
        return ObjectContextInUse;
    }
}

public void Initialize()
{
    InitializeContext();
    InitializeDatabase();
}
```

**Therefore**, currently the only possible way to get the primary key(s) is through object set, entity set, key members, etc as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253943/entity-framework-code-first-find-primary-key)

```
var keyNames = set.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);
```

Comment: Great Answer! ... Regarding to [KeyAttribute] ... It's better to use 'Where' instead of 'FirstOrDefault' because some of my entities with Composite Key.