# Generic Repository in C# Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to retrieve multiple records by giving array of primary key and I have to make generic method of it for all the entities.

```
private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;
      /// <summary>
            /// Get entity by identifier
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="id">Identifier</param>
            /// <returns>Entity</returns>
            public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
            {
                return Entities.Find(id);
            }




 /// <summary>
        /// Get entity by identifier
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identifier</param>
        /// <returns>Entity</returns>
        public virtual List<TEntity> GetByIds(int id[])
        {
               // want to make it generic
            return Entities.Where(x=>id.Contains(id));
        }

    /// <summary>
        /// Gets an entity set
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> Entities
        {
            get
            {
                if (_entities == null)
                    _entities = _context.Set<TEntity>();

                return _entities;
            }
        }
```

problem here is that my Entities doesn't have ID columns, for eg Product has ProductId, Order has OrderId. I don't want to change my db columns to Id.

```
Entities.Where(x=>id.Contains(id));
```

I want my entities columns to be same as they are now. can I achieve a generic search method with this db structure to find multiple records?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityFramework 6 How to get identity-field with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141955/entityframework-6-how-to-get-identity-field-with-reflection)

Comment: Or, embrace the fact that the `DbSet` already _is_ a generic repository?

Comment: Not another generic repository. DbConext is the unit of work and DbSet is the repository.

Comment: @Fabio No, it doesn't. `Find` accepts *single* PK consisting of one or more values (in case of composite PK).

Comment: hi @IvanStoev Note warning: This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.entitytype.findprimarykey?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Internal_EntityType_FindPrimaryKey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use EF Core provided metadata services like [FindEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imodel.findentitytype?view=efcore-2.1) and [FindPrimaryKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype.findprimarykey?view=efcore-2.1) to get the PK property name. Then you can use it to access the PK value inside LINQ to Entities query using another EF Core provided useful method [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-2.1).

Something like this:

```
public virtual List<TEntity> GetByIds(int[] ids)
{
    var idName = _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity))
        .FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Single().Name;
    return Entities
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(EF.Property<int>(x, idName)))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: hi @IvanStoev what are the performance implications of doing it this way? Does .FindPrimaryKey().Properties. cause a schema lock on database table in trying to find primary key? Does it cause any application slowness? What if we create partial classes to auto generate the Ids? What are the advantages /disadvantages in each method performance wise ? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57261804/net-core-create-generic-repository-interface-id-mapping-for-all-tables-auto-cod

Comment: posted question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386900/generic-repository-primary-id-key-performance

Comment: Note warning: This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.entitytype.findprimarykey?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Internal_EntityType_FindPrimaryKey

Comment: @jerrythomas38 You are looking at the wrong method documentation (the internal class implementation). The correct link is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype.findprimarykey?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IEntityType_FindPrimaryKey. All the methods used in the answer are public.

Comment: greatl ! thanks I would love to get your opinion also on the performance question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386900/generic-repository-primary-id-key-performance

Answer (score 3):

You can have different names in your application model and your database model. You will have to map your Model Ids to the name in database:

In your Mapping you will have something similar to this for every entity:
this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ProductId");